# Visual Studio 2013 debug can't find config file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Have loaded an old project in Visual Studio 2013. Ran a few times with no problems. Was looking through folders on my machine earlier and found a folder where I host my local sites called sitename-site. Thinking it might be an old copy I deleted and emptied my recycle bin out of habit. Now when I try to run the project it says it can't find the config file, which it seems to think is in this folder I deleted when there is still a web.config file in the directory that holds the actual site.

Any ideas what's going on and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: First, try to avoid doing anything which might write to the drive from which you deleted the folder. If you have a second computer which you can install the drive in, that would be ideal for recovering your files. Either way, you can use a utility such as [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds) which you can download onto a USB drive and unzip it on that USB drive to try and get the folder back. If you get the files back, you can then investigate in VS as to which file came from that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure why vs decided to create a random new folder and put my web.config in there but have managed to get the project working again by setting the server to Local IIS in the Web section of the project properties.

Hopefully this will be useful to anyone else with a similar problem.